# File from Intent.data.toString doesn'exist

Tags: android, android-intent

Keeping it simple, I have an intent where the user select a song, from this code 
`onActivityResult(...Intent data){
    Log.d("path", data.toString()
}`

Which returns the following string

`file:///storage/nameOfSd/music/song%artist.mp3`

But when I try to read the meta of the song with 

`MediaMetadataRetriever mr=...
 mr.setDataSource(data.toString());`

Throws an exception saying that the file doesn't exist, but it does.
I've readed about removing the "file://" from the data string but Im not sure. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try with real path of file.

```
Uri selectedSongUri = data.getData();
String path = getRealPathFromURI(selectedSongUri);
```

Then write this method for getting real path of file.

```
    public String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
      Cursor cursor = null;
      try {
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } finally {
           if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It trows "Java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int android.database.Cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference"

Comment: @DaniTorres Please try updated code. https://gist.github.com/hu2di/6a3be01bdd4eb6b39508e03c9cc1e9d6

Answer (score 0):

`MediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource` expects the path of the file and you are passing it the URI.

Use `void setDataSource (Context context, Uri uri)` instead, check [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html#setDataSource(android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri)).

In order to get the URI of the file you just need to do:

```
URI uri = data.getData()
```